# Science fiction novel, set in an alternate future or present, where lovers were matched based on profession

Tags: story-identification, books

I read this in the early noughties. It would’ve been published around that time.

I don’t remember much besides the fact there was more than one book. Below I will list the recurring themes between books, before revealing details of books that I remember.

- The story is set in the U.K., where Scotland and The North are far wealthier than The South (namely anything south of the Midlands).
- The protagonist loves someone, however they are incompatible because they’re professions do not produce optimal babies.
- there is some kind of floating robot helper for our protagonist
- the protagonist is a detective of some kind
- the country is run by “the authorities” which seems to be some kind of computer software, but it’s unclear from what I recall.

Book specific details

- the first book prominently featured a bow and arrow. It’s relevance I don’t know.
- the second book I recall featured some sort of Olympic venue in London, I believe someone drowned while laying foundations for one of the buildings. Something I explicitly remember is the abundance of snakes in London
- the third book I recall predominantly featured ice and something in the far north.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The 'Traces' series by Malcolm Rose. The boy is called Luke, and is a detective. he has a robot helper called Mal. His wannabe girlfriend is called Jade, and is a musician. The first book is Framed. The book with the swimmer is called Final lap, and is actually the 5th book in the series.

Comment: This sounds like it was probably it, let me dig a bit more. Providing some more details in the answer would help.